# Запросить поле из внешней таблицы по ключу

Tags: sql, innodb, mysql

Доброго времени суток.

Есть, в базе, таблица жанров:

```
CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name_genres` (`name`),
  KEY `description_genres` (`description`),
  CONSTRAINT `genres_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`name`) REFERENCES `names` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `genres_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`description`) REFERENCES `text` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Вместо названия и описания жанра в записи хранятся внешние ключи, ссылающиеся на таблицы `names` (хранит текстовые поля) и `text` (хранит многострочные тексты). Есть ли способ, используя механизм внешних ключей InnoDB, получить, одним sql запросом, данные по всем или части жанров?

Пока использовал такой код:

```
SELECT `names`.`name`  FROM `names`, `genres` WHERE `names`.`id` = `genres`.`name`
```

Он работает но, подозреваю, далеко не оптимален, для данной ситуации.

Маленькая ремарка для тех, кто задастся вопросом "Нахрена две базы?": Интерфейсы некоторых сайтов надо переводить)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то просто [`JOIN`](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html), вернее, два соединения.

> То есть, вытаскивать данные о внешних ключах и соединять таблицы на основе этих данных?

Именно так.

> Я подозревал, что этим всё закончится, но надеялся, что подобный механизм уже разработан в самой MySQL.

Я не слышал о таком, хотя плохо знаю MySQL.

Comment: @msi, нет, это не то: В вашем примере явным образом задаются поля для сопоставления записей, в то время как мне нужно, чтобы сопоставление шло на основе внешних ключей, уже заданных в структуре БД.

Comment: То, что вам нужно, называется естественным соединением (NATURAL JOIN). Но, чтобы его использовать, соединяемые столбцы должны называться одинаково. Переименуйте столбцы.

Comment: @msi тоже не то, к сожалению. Во-первых, `NATURAL JOIN` просто сравнивает одноимённые столбцы, а мне нужно, чтобы запрос использовал механизм внешних ключей. Во-вторых, мне нужно не слияние одноимённых столбцов, а слияние таблиц, с исключением внешних ключей, например так:

    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": 15,
    "text": 20
    }
    +
    {
    "id": 15,
    "name": "Детектив"
    }
    +
    {
    "id": 20,
    "text": "Бла-бла-бла"
    }
    =
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Детектив",
    "text": "Бла-бла-бла"
    }

Comment: @Risto,
Похоже, что вы пытаетесь совместить две разных технологии - SQL/NoSQL. :-)

Тогда обращайтесь к метаданным и стройте запросы динамически.

Comment: @msi, то есть, вытаскивать данные о внешних ключах и соединять таблицы на основе этих данных? Я подозревал, что этим всё закончится, но надеялся, что подобный механизм уже разработан в самой MySQL. Ладно, отрицательный результат -- тоже результат.

Comment: >  вытаскивать данные о внешних ключах и соединять таблицы на основе этих данных?

Да.

>  но надеялся, что подобный механизм уже разработан в самой MySQL

Я не слышал о таком, хотя плохо знаю MySQL.